# Question about finding expected value and variance of x given the mean.

Tags: probability, random-variables, means

Suppose Y is distributed as an exponential random variable with mean 0.5 and given Y = y, X is
distributed as an exponential random variable with mean y. What is E(X) and Var(X)?

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]]=\int \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]f_Y(y)dy$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: Oh okay, I'll be sure to do that next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As d.k.o. says, use the **Law of Iterated Expectations**:
$$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\sf E}}\begin{align}\E(X) = &\; \E(\E(X\mid Y))\\ = &\; \int_0^\infty \E(X\mid Y) f_Y(y)\operatorname d x\end{align}$$

Likewise the **Law of Iterated Variance**:

$$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{\sf Var}}\begin{align}\Var(X) = & \; \E(\Var (X\mid Y))+\Var(\E(X\mid Y)) \\ = & \;\int_0^\infty \Var(X\mid Y) f_Y(y)\operatorname d y+\int_0^\infty \Big(\E(X\mid Y)-\underbrace{\E(\E(X\mid Y))}_{:=\E(X)}\Big)^2 f_Y(y)\operatorname d y\end{align}$$

Now, for exponential distributions of given means these terms are :

$$\begin{align}\E(X\mid Y) = &  y \\ \Var(X\mid Y) = & y^2 \\ f_Y(y) = & 2 e^{-2y} \quad\Bbb I_{(0<y)}\end{align}$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you very much. Part of what was confusing me was that I read the question incorrectly but now I understand how to approach it.